# Is it possible in Android to record something played by MediaPlayer? 

Tags: java, android, media-player, audio-streaming, audio-recording

In my application I am doing live audio streaming using Android media player. I want to capture the sound stream played by MediaPlayer. Is there is way to record using Android MediaPlayer instead of MediaRecorder? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

While it is a non-trivial undertaking, you can write your own "MediaPlayer" that implements whatever streaming protocol you are using and writes the stream to a file instead of the speaker.